# jquery adding new select option and send data to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a validation on the revenue field. If I run the code when the jquery code doesn't get invoked then the form gets submitted without any validation problem.

But if a user selects "no revenue" option in the first select then the jquery gets invoked ant the new `$0` gets inserted and selected in the 2nd select form. If I check out the new HTML code everything looks good (new option is there and selected) but on submission it raises "revenue can't be blank error". So for some reason when the validation runs it thinks the field is empty.

I guess this is connected to my jQuery code. How can I solve this problem?

form (for showing original select options)

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <div><%= f.label :revenue_type, "Revenue Type" %></div>
      <%= f.select :revenue_type, ["recurring revenue", "non-recurring revenue", "no revenue"],
        { :selected => "recurring revenue" }, { "data-behavior" => "revenue-type-select", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div><%= f.label :revenue %></div>
      <%= f.select :revenue, ["< $100k", "$100k < $1M", "> $1M"], {},
        { "data-behavior" => "revenue-number-select", class: "form-control" } %>
    </div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-behavior="revenue-type-select"]', function (event) {
  if ($(this).val() === "no revenue") {
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]').append(new Option("$0", "$0"));
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"] option[value="$0"]').attr("selected", "selected").change();
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]').prop("disabled", true);
  } 
  else {
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"] option[value="$0"]').remove();
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]' ).prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

Html after jquery code invoked before submit:

```
<select data-behavior="revenue-number-select" class="form-control" name="company[revenue]" id="company_revenue" disabled="">
  <option value="< $100k">< $100k</option>
  <option value="$100k < $1M">$100k < $1M</option>
  <option value="> $1M">> $1M</option>
  <option value="$0" selected="selected">$0</option>
</select>
```

UPDATE

company.rb

```
validates :revenue, presence: { message: "can't be blank" }
```

This validates if the given value is `nil` or empty like `("", " ")`. It's weird since if I choose any of the original options like `< $100k` then the validation passes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of changing the selected attribute you can try to change the selection of the  directly by

setting `selectedIndex` to the last index of your select list using `.prop`

See Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7da197j4/1/

Comment: @SzilardMagyar I added a JSFiddle

Comment: Thibault, thanks for the JSFiddle. I checked the code out and still get the validation error. With this code, after the jquery invoked, the html still shows the proper value ($0), but for some reason there is no `selected="selected"` on any option in the html. In my original solution there is `selected="selected"` as you see (I don't know if it matters)

Comment: @SzilardMagyar Could you please post your server side validation?

Comment: Thibault, found the problem, but have yet to find the solution. So if I take out this line `$('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]').prop("disabled", true);` then it's working fine. Do you have any idea how to make disabling working?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. Maybe it's not the best but working:

```
$(document).on('change', '[data-behavior="revenue-type-select"]', function (event) {
  if ($(this).val() === "no revenue") {
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]').append(new Option("$0", "$0"));
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"] option[value="$0"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]').prop("disabled", true);
  } 
  else {
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"] option[value="$0"]').remove();
    $('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]' ).prop("disabled", false);
  };
});

$(document).on('bind', '[data-behavior="company-form"]', function (event) {
  $(this).find('[data-behavior="revenue-number-select"]').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: I didn't know a disabled selectlist couldn't be binded, but good to know. Glad you solved it.